# chart recorder for ROS?

Tags: ros, visualization, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any suggestions for strip chart recorder software for use when viewing live (and recorded) streams of timeseries data? Ideally, the software would have a nice GUI that allows one to zoom both vertically and horizontally and show multiple ROS topics simultaneously.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9945/chart-recorder-for-ros?/) by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2011-05-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what you are looking for is [rxplot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot).

This will produce a strip chart that updates for you while ROS is running.  It can also be used with playback.

For pure playback, you can use [rxbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxbag).  rxbag is also slightly more extensible than rxplot, and you can right plugins for visualizing any application specific data you may need.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-10-13**:
The problem with rxbag is that it cannot plot simultaneously data from different topics (in the same figure). rxplot can

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-13**:
Well that's just awesome.  Today I Learned.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-05-13**:
Actually I learned recently (over here: http://answers.ros.org/question/432/analyzing-ros-messages) that you can also use rxbag to plot topics at runtime, and not only when playing back bagfiles.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also just discovered [streamvis](http://code.google.com/p/streamvis/), which looks interesting. (I haven't tried it yet.)

---

Originally posted by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) with karma: 171 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1